# Finding arrays that satisfy the average case

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm not sure whether to post this is Mathematics or here, but it's Algorithms, so I'm going to try here.

Essentially, I have an algorithm to find the median value in an array.  It is, in essence, the quick select algorithm.

What I want to do is find arrays of numbers that satisfy the average case.  I.E, when the array length is 5, the average number of basic operations is 6.  I want to find the relationship between the arrays that output 6, so that I can programatically build an array of length `x`, and get the number of operations

I've been generating a tonne of arrays to try and find a pattern by hand, and I can't see it.  I have been using the permutations of {1,2,3,4,5}, and going higher than that and it becomes too unwieldy to look at (minimum 720 arrays), and lower there is not enough variation to find a pattern.

The way I found 6 basic operations was to run the algorithm over ever permutation of {1,2,3,4,5}, and output the result into a list, which I then piped into python and ran `sum(list)/len(list)`.  I then manually went through and found the arrays that output 6, and looked at them.  First alone, and then in the group, to see if I could find any characteristics.

The first pivot is always zero.

I'm either looking for some kind of formula to generate these arrays, or a way to analyse the data to obtain the pattern.

Edit:
I should clarify that I am looking for a way to programmatically generate arrays that meets the criteria of 'average case' for the quick select.

Comment: You can make your question more clear by adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have two questions here. One is probably algorithmic (but it's unclear what kind of algorithm you're looking for) and the other seems to involve statistical analysis. The former is an appropriate question here and the latter is not. Please update the question to focus on the algorithmic aspect and open another question in stats or mathematics for the mathematical part.

Comment: How many of the permutations gave you an answer of 6? Have you tried looking at the permutations that give you some other number, and see if you can find patterns in them? Have you considered [counting the inversions](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/) to see if that gives you any insight?